# DropDownList selected value set using jQuery is lost after page postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

DropDownList selected value set using jQuery is lost after page postback. My question is how do I retain the value changed/selected using jQuery after the page postback? Please note that I have disabled my DropDownList on the client before posting back and my forms submitdisabledcontrols property set to true declaratively.

Comment: Is your form submitting the data in POST or GET?

Comment: @Niklas The form is submitting the data using the POST method.

Comment: Can you include a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can use view state . Set viewState = true for our drop down.

Comment: By default the view state property is enabled still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an html-select instead of an ASP.NET-DropDownList:

```
<select ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" />
```

You could access the selected value in following way:

```
If Not Request(DropDownList1.ClientID) Is Nothing Then
    Dim selectedValue = CInt(Request(DropDownList1.ClientID))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put dropdownlist inside the

```
if(!isPostBack) 
{ 

ddl.DataSource = "...";

ddl.DataBind(); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am already doing what you have suggested but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

is not setting the value, otherwise it's lost on every postback.

You could also submit the form using jquery by having a client onclick event which then enables the dropdown and submits the form, so that when the postback reloads the controls, the view state of the control should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

try using the the jquery live function

$('selector').live('click', function(){ /*your-code-goes here*/});

this will persist the event on your page